# POST /apex/wwv_flow.ajax returns with 404 (Not found) on pages submit and load

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In the middle of development process of an application in **Oracle APEX** I started to get really weird `404 (Not Found)` exceptions from APEX engine.

Sometimes APEX responds `404 (Not Found)` on different actions. Points where I can get these exceptions may be different:

- When an AJAX call is made:
  [image]
- When a modal page is submitted:
  [image]
- When a page is changed in the App Builder:
  [image]
- Sometimes even when a developer is logged in to the App Builder:
  [image]

The weirdest thing about all this is that this exception occurs only once in a row. For example, If I press a button to submit a page, I get the exception the first time, when I press the button the second time, everything works.

One of the examples how to reproduce the exeption with the 100% probabilty - I have a page with several interactive reports on it. Each interactive report has a link column to edit the row. When a user clicks the link, a modal window appears with a form, then they should click the button "Save". So the steps to reproduce the error:

1. Open the page with interactive reports.
2. Choose a row to edit, click the link column.
3. Change anything in the modal window, click save.
4. The error appears.
5. Click `Save` again.
6. Data is saved, modal window is closed and the report refreshed.

In the browser javascript console I see the following:

```
POST http://<my_ip_address>/apex/wwv_flow.ajax 404 (Not found)
XHR failed loading: POST "http://<my_ip_address>/apex/wwv_flow.ajax".
```

Also, I opened [a discussion on OTN](https://community.oracle.com/message/14505585) about the topic where I gave some additional information.

Comment: I found out that this error somehow related to `Application Dynamic List of Values`. Because when I eliminated columns in the reports `based on LOV` and changed component types on the edit form from `Popup LOV` to `Text Field`, the error stopped to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using trial and error method, the reason of the error was found.

It appeared, that **the error is related to items or report columns which base on `LOV` (List of Values). And only when these `LOV` are based on pipelined functions which return plenty of rows** (let's say 1 hundred and more).

This is what happens:

1. User1 submits a page where there're several items based on `LOV` (which in their turn base on database pipelined functions). For example, several `Popup LOV` items. User1 set some values and pressed the submit button.
2. `APEX accept process` recieves the request, tries to fetch rows from LOV, but don't need all of them, and as far as I understand, tries to close the cursor.
3. Pipelined fuction raises an exception - `ORA-06548: no more rows needed`. This is absolutely legitimate behaviour.
4. APEX engine reacts inadequately on it, and returns `404 (Not Found)` as a result of the request.
5. `APEX show process` wraps this exception and returns it to User1. User1 sees one of the pictures I shown above.

So the solution is to suppress any exceptions generated by pipelined functions which are used in LOV components. After doing so, everything started to work well.

I assume it **an Oracle APEX bug** because of three reasons - the reaction on the pipelined function is inadequate, the generated error in response is intransparent for both developers and users and it's not even logged properly anywhere.